# I want to display the active window

Tags: winapi

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd, hWndTopMost, 0, 0,
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Width,
    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Height,
    SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);
```

This is my code to display my form full screen and at the top, but when I am inducing alt+ctrl+delete, the task manager is activated at the back of this form even though my form is not active. I understand by the colour of caption bar. This problem is only occuring in win8 os. I want to display the task manager which is active but without losing the properties of my app like hooking. How can I achieve it by changing the flags of the above?

Comment: Thanks potter for the edit u have made.Do u have the answer for the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve it with documented WinAPI functions.
The Task Manager in Windows 8 uses an undocumented method in order to become on top of all windows, including the top-most ones.

Specifically, it uses the `CreateWindowInBand` WinAPI function to achieve the effect.

Comment: Paul,any other methods to achieve the above?

Comment: But in my application,I can prevent taskbar from displaying eventhough it is active.It is appearing behind my form or my form can hide it from displaying.